# How to connect Angular Controller to HTML?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add a basic angular controller to my HTML page, but can't get it connected properly.  I've been using ng serve to view the page on localhost:4200, and the HTML loads fine, but the js file isn't being loaded at all, from what I can tell.  I'm new to angular, so I'm sure I'm just missing something, and any help would be appreciated.

Repo: https://github.com/jollygreenegiant/EtsyCalculator

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/jollygreenegiant/EtsyCalculator

Thanks!

Comment: Note, `angularjs` != `angular`. This project is [tag:angular] (i.e., version 2 and above). Your "controller" is written in angularjs, which is not at all compatible.

Comment: Please include all relevant code as a [mcve] in the question itself, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so. Also, Angular and AngularJS are two very different frameworks; take care when applying the correct tags.

Comment: What do you mean with "connected properly"? Are you getting errors?

Comment: The [Upgrading from AngularJS to Angular](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) guide is a good place to start Angular concepts.

Comment: Note that Stackblitz lets you import a github repo directly into an editable, runnable format: https://stackblitz.com/docs#import-from-github I added the link to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing Angular 1 (angularjs) and (angular) 2+ which are different paradigms inside your project.  This file in your project is an AngularJS 1 file, while the rest are Angular 2+ files (https://github.com/jollygreenegiant/EtsyCalculator/blob/master/src/app/controller.js).  You probably mixed up your tutorials somewhere, unless you're trying to blend the two technologies.  I think it's doubtful that's what you're trying to do as you'll be learning two things at once.  If you need another component it should be written in the style like your app.component.ts is, not using old Angularjs patterns.